# Having problem with centering text in a Navbar in Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I created a navbar in Bootstrap, and I would like to center the content in it.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container"> 
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">
      <i class="bi bi-list-check"></i>
      Nav Text
    </span> 
  </div>
</nav>
```

In a CSS file, I tried several things, but nothing works. For example flex:

```
.navbar { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

It just seems that nothing influences the navbar. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Nav Text" text is inside a `div` element that has the class `.container`. This `div` is inside another `nav` element that has the class `navbar` that is a `flexbox` container. The default styles (boostrap you are using) justifies content to the start of the flexbox (`justify-content:flex-start`). You have to override this default styling using the value `center` for `justify-content`. Also, you have to use `!important` to override the default style. Please see this screenshot.

https://prnt.sc/1xfrtcp

And example code below.

```css
.navbar > .container {
justify-content:center!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container"> 
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">
      <i class="bi bi-list-check"></i>
      Centered Nav Text
    </span> 
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Also try to read some parts at least of this guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or other similar guide on flexbox. It is a very commonly used property and as you can see very useful too.